# Import CSV (Excel table) into SQLite?

Tags: excel, database, sqlite, csv

I'm trying to import a Excel table into SQLite database unsuccessfully.

Excel cvs file (**excel.cvs**) looks like this:

```
Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4
text 11,text 12,text 13,text 14
text 21,text 22,text 23,text 24
text 31,text 32,text 33,text 34
...
...
```

And the BOM character `ÿþ` appears at the beginning of the data stream which means the text file is encoded in UTF-16 little endian.

In SQLite I import the excel file into a new table but it fails and outputs:

```
sqlite3> .mode csv
sqlite3> .separator ,
sqlite3> .import excel.cvs mytable
CREATE TABLE mytable(...) failed: duplicate column name:
```

And If I create **mytable** previously and then import **excel.cvs** into it, all data fields are empty:

```
sqlite3> CREATE TABLE mytable(a,b,c,d);
sqlite3> .import excel.cvs mytable
sqlite3> SELECT * FROM mytable;
"","","",""
"","","",""
"","","",""
...
```

I have researched a lot on the internet and SO but I can't find a solution. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

SQLite 3.30.1

excel.csv: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: Convert the file to utf-8 first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the user Shawn has suggested to me, I was able to import the cvs by previously converting it to UTF-8 encoding.

Since I'm using Linux, I did:

```
$ iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 excel.cvs > excel_uft8.cvs
```

For more info: [iconv(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv)

Thanks Shawn :)